# Understanding the multiplication in celluar chain complex of $\mathbb{R}P^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Understanding the multiplication in celluar chain complex of $\mathbb{R}P^n$

If $n$ is even the sequence goes:

$... 0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^2 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^0 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^2 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^0 ... \rightarrow^0 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$

And for $n$ odd the sequence goes:

$... 0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^0 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^2 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^0 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow^2 ... \rightarrow^2 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$

Why does the map alternate  between multiplication by two and zero?

I understand why it is so for the map from the $2$ skeleton to the $1$ skeleton, you are wrapping the boundary of a disc $D^2$ twice around a circle $S^1$. In my mind, every map would be multiplication by $2$, but obviously this is not true.

Would somebody care to explain? Thanks!

Comment: The sign of the antipodal map alternates.

Comment: Like Justin says if you carefully keep track of all the conventions involved in calculating the degree and adding maps of spheres, you will get either that the maps are the identity plus the antipodal or the inverse of that. Since the antipodal map switches degree you get the alternations. Alternatively you could provide a simplicial structure and do the calculation there.

Comment: In case that you are still confused, have a look at http://www.math.wisc.edu/~maxim/Topnotes2.pdf, bottom of page 4.